# Magento editor making code disappear

Tags: magento2, tinymce

In my `Magento` admin panel, some of the codes are mystically getting disappeared.
When I put this code in the editor

```
    <li class="level1 mmegamenu-644"><a class="mobile-click-anchor" 
       href="/women/what-s-trending.html"> <span class="mega-menu-sub- 
 title"> What's Trending </span> </a>
      <span class="toggle-menu"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class=""><span class="icon-plus"></span></a></span>
       <ul id="mobile-menu-cat-644-1" class="sub-menu mobile- subcategory">
         <li class="level2 mmegamenu-667"><a href="/women/what-s- 
          trending/holiday-gift-guide.html"> Holiday Gift Guide </a></li>
          <li class="level2 mmegamenu-668"><a href="/women/what-s- 
           trending/animal-prints.html"> Animal Prints </a></li>
         <li class="level2 mmegamenu-669"><a href="/women/what-s-trending/plaid- 
   suits.html"> Plaid Suits </a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
```

and then clicking on `Show/Hide Editor` it makes this code disappear

```
<span class="toggle-menu"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class=""><span class="icon-plus"></span></a></span>
```

Code in editor(Before clicking `Show/Hide Editor` )

[image]

Code after clicking on `Show/Hide Editor` or saving it first time opening the same piece of code for updating.

[image]

Whats this issue. I don't understand.

The same thing happens with this code also.

```
<ul class="list-inline left-parent-header">
<li><a href="#">Privacy Policy&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="social-links">
<li><a href="#" target="_self"> <i class="ti-pinterest-alt"></i></a> 
</li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="ti-instagram"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="ti-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="ti-linkedin"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="ti-vimeo"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

This makes below code disappear

```
<ul class="list-inline left-parent-header">
 <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your HTML is invalid (no closing ul)

Comment: @PhilippSander I did , in that case only except that <div> tag everything inside div tag disappears and what's remians <div> tag

Comment: @PhilippSander  html is perfect , I didn't put the all HTML here , maybe I missed it, it gets vanished for full html code also

Comment: HTML is not perfect... you a NOT closing the <ul>

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: @PhilippSander  I said i demonstrated this bug with less code, the original code is way too long, so if I close the ul tag or not it will anyhow get disappeared. And it's my bad I took snippet of unclosed tab. That's not an issue

Comment: @PhilippSander Hey i have updated my question

Comment: which Magento 2 version you are using?

Comment: @magefms Magento 2.3.0

Answer (score 3):

Magento's editor doesn't allow empty html tags.

For example `<li><a href="#" target="_self"> <i class="ti-pinterest-alt"></i></a> 
</li>` - this shows visually an icon to the user, but with a pseudo `:before` content which isn't an element.

And the editor "cleans" this up.

To bypass this, you can insert an `&nbsp;` (space) in the empty tags, like this:

`<li><a href="#" target="_self"><i class="ti-pinterest-alt">&nbsp;</i></a> 
</li>`

Also I suggest editing this code:

`<span class="toggle-menu"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class=""><span class="icon-plus"></span></a></span>`

to:

`<span class="toggle-menu"><a href="#"><span class="icon-plus">&nbsp;</span></a></span>`

the `javascript:void(0)` will disappear otherwise as well.

Magento's editor is TinyMCE and there is an option on the editor to disable removal of empty tags, but that would require knowledge of how the editor is initialized (which I don't know).

If you really want to disable this feature and find out how the editor is initialized, this answer will probably help in disabling it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467480/how-to-prevent-tinymce-from-stripping-empty-tags-from-input